# Mapping a Core Data model property type

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Is it possible to map a property of a Core Data model from one type to another using only a Core Data Mapping Model or do you need to define a custom Mapping Policy?

For example lets say I have a model called *Show* with the property *identifier* of type *Integer 32* and I want to map it to a *String*. This is just a hypothetical example. You can of course do this in code as needed in the ManagedObject subclass.

I am looking to know if it is possible in general.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to map it to a string?

Comment: It doesn't matter so much why I have to. The important thing is how I would go about converting a property type. I have other properties that needs to be converted as well.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem, I cannot for the life of me have a smooth transition with my mapping policy, all ive done is change the attribute type, everything works through the mapping policy, but I cannot figure out why the data from version 1 is not saving the values in their appopriate properties in version 2. All the values from one column are in another column in version 2 when it should have mapped appropriately. Have you figured out the problem to your situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert properties from one type to another programatically. Taking your given example:

```
// in your NSManagedObject subclass
@property (nonatomic) int32_t identifier;

// someplace else
NSNumber *identifierNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:managedObject.identifier];
NSString *identifierString = [identifierNumber stringValue];
```

Comment: I know that I can manually convert the property as needed. This is not what I'm looking for. I am asking if you can in general convert the type of a property using a mapping model